# how can define table record is exiest or not in table in database using db-table in zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

i am using zend framework.
i want to define product name is exist or not if not then insert the product name.

i am using this code in controller

```
$this->product_tbl = new Application_Model_DbTable_Producttbl();

$product_name = 'mobile';

$productresult = $this->product_tbl->fetchRow($this->product_tbl->select()->where('product_name ='.$product_name));

 if(!$productresult){

                        // do when productresult is null

}

Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mobile' in 'where clause'
```

my question is if `product_name` is not found then display a simple message "row is not found"

Comment: can you provide the structure of your table too...is `product_name` and `mobile` both are columns ?

Comment: thanks but i solve my problem..

Comment: 'product_name' is field of table and $proudct_name is variable

Comment: `'product_name ='.$product_name` ==> `'product_name = ?', $product_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->product_tbl = new Application_Model_DbTable_Producttbl(); // project db table

$product_name = 'mobile'; // project_name variable declare and store value 'mobile'

$productresult = $this->product_tbl->fetchAll($this->product_tbl->select()->where('product_name = ?', $product_name)); // Fetch result and store in $productresult

$row = $productresult->current(); // set current()

if($row == NULL){

        echo "row is null";
}
```

i user current() function which is return null value when $productresult have a no any value...